# how to get the last read post name by logged user in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need the get the name of the last post read by logged user in Wordpress. To use it as a hint on the logged user dashboard. "Your last read post was {post_name}"

Could you please advise how can i get this last read post ID or name? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code in your theme's functions.php or plugin file.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'wp_user_last_view_post_func' );
function wp_user_last_view_post_func(){
    if (is_user_logged_in() AND is_singular() AND get_post_type()==="post"){
        update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'last_view_post_id',get_the_ID());
    }
}

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'last_post_dashboard_widgets');
function last_post_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('last_read_post_widget', 'Last Read Post', 'last_read_post_widget_dashboard');
}

function last_read_post_widget_dashboard() {
    $last_post_id = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'last_view_post_id',true);
    echo '<p>Your last read post was <a href="'.get_permalink($last_post_id).'" target="_blank">'.get_the_title($last_post_id).'</a></p>';
}
```

You can see last read post on wordpress dashboard like this : [See Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IU70.png)

I hope this may be helpful to you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much for a fast response and a detailed answer, maybe you could show also an example of the modification to show last read post on the FRONTEND for the logged user, for a custom post type "Lessons".